# Assigning percentage-based heights to Bootstrap rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row

How can I assign a `height` of `15%` to a BootStrap row?

It only appears to work for me if I assign a height of `15px`, otherwise I end up with a height of `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean 15% of the page height to be assigned to the row, you can use viewport units.

```
.my-row {
    height: 15vh;
}
```

This means your row height is 15% of the page height.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a percentage-based `height` on an element, you **must** have a **fixed** height on one of the element's parents.

If the element with fixed height is the immediate parent, you only need a percentage-based height on the target element.

If the fixed-height is on an element that is higher up in the DOM than the **immediate parent**, you need to specify a percentage-based height for **every** element in between the target element and the fixed-height element.

Here's a working example, using the immediate parent `.container`:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.row {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: blue;
  height: 80%; /* corresponds to 160px, because 160 is 80% of 200 */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)